# How to fix WordPress template error that breaks the page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I'm working on a preexisting wordpress-based website.

This is a multi-site installation using 3 different themes.

The themes are: DWT Listings, WpResidence, and Careerfy.

Themes, WordPress, every should already be updated to the last version.

I keep having this problem that brakes the pages.

This one, in particular, come out on the listing page with DWT Listings:

> *Notice: Undefined index: enabled in /nas/content/live/cwlife2/wp-content/themes/dwt-listing/template-parts/listing-detial/with_solid/listing-detial-1.php on line 24*
>
> *Notice: Undefined index: enabled in /nas/content/live/cwlife2/wp-content/themes/dwt-listing/template-parts/listing-detial/sidebar/sidebar.php on line 27*

Any idea of what is causing the problem?

Comment: You'll need to share the code of those two files (or at least the lines being mentioned in the error messages) so we can help out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the theme but the issue is that in the code they check for an option to be enabled. And this is not defined when it is not disabled. But are you sure that those notices are breaking your site? or are there more errors?

```
$layout = $dwt_listing_options['dwt_listing_sidebar-layout-manager']['enabled'];
```

you could put an if statement around  that block, like this:

```
if ( isset( $dwt_listing_options['dwt_listing_sidebar-layout-manager'] ) && isset( $dwt_listing_options['dwt_listing_sidebar-layout-manager']['enabled'] )  )
```

hopefully this helps you in he right direction.

Comment: $dwt_listing_options is defined on top of the file as global